# How to iterate and store variables in a dictionary?

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop

I am new to python and my coding experience so far is with MATLAB.

I am trying to understand more about lists and dictionaries as i am using a library about DOEs that takes an dictionary as a passing argument.

But my trouble so far is that this dictionary assumes the form of ex.

DOE={'Elastic Modulus':[10,20,30], 'Density':[1,2,3], 'Thickness':[2,3,5]}

But i need this dictionary to be user defined, for example:

1. Have an input to define how many variables are needed (in this example are 3: Elastic Modulus','Density'and 'Thickness)
2. as the variables are defined, it should be able to store values in the dictionary over a for loop.

Is this possible using dictionaries?

Or is it better to use a list and convert in a dicionary later?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One can add keys and the corresponding values to a dict one at a time like so:

```
my_dict = {}

num_entries = int(input("How many entries "))

for _ in range(num_entries):
    key = input("Enter the key: ")
    value = input("Enter the value: ")
    my_dict[key] = value
```

Presumably you would have a loop to do the entry of key and value for the number of values you wish to enter. Also if you are in python 2 it needs to be raw_input rather than input function. [Edit: Showing how to do the loop, since I noticed that was part of your question]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!